# How can I display a 3d Model in Jframe

Tags: java, swing, 3d, java-3d, vrml

I do some search with my friend google but i can't find anything that help. so i come here to ask a question

can I display a 3d model (.wrl or .obj ) in Jframe?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any "Out of the box" way to do it. But I'd suggest that you try and learn openGL with `LWJGL` (Light Wight Java Game Library):

http://www.lwjgl.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any library such as LWJGL you can try and make a "SoftEngine". [SoftEngine - Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLWBFnl76E8)

[SoftEngine - David Rousset](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2013/06/13/tutorial-series-learning-how-to-write-a-3d-soft-engine-from-scratch-in-c-typescript-or-javascript.aspx)

Trying to create a soft engine is good as it will teach you the fundamentals, but it also takes quite a bit of time and knowledge.